# A workaround to redirect a request to cache server with HTTP (not dns)

Tags: http, redirect, load-balancing

Suppose a browser requests

```
aaa.com
```

and that domain is hosting in a loadbalancer.
Dns will do its job and make browser find the loadbalancer for that request.
After the loadbalancer gets request, It should redirect the browser to a suitable reverse cacheserver.
The methods of redirecting in http (3XX) and Location makes browser to change its Host directive in request header. Than means if cache server's address is cache.bbb.com, the Host directive would change to cache.bbb.com and that would ruin all the cache mechanism because the cache server was expecting aaa.com to find out the right origin.

Also this would change the address of aaa.com in the browser's address bar to cache.bbb.com.

If I could use dns it could be solved easily. But I'm still looking for a solution in HTTP.

All I want is somehow telling to browser to ask the same domain from another address
 like what dns does.
Do you guys think of a way to solve this in HTTP or any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

> After the loadbalancer gets request, It should redirect the browser to
>   a suitable reverse cacheserver. The methods of redirecting in http (3XX) and Location makes browser to change its Host directive in request header.

I'm not sure where you are getting this information; because this is not typically how load balancers work.

If they did do this, then no POST requests would work because a 3xx would cause a GET request from the browser, losing any POST payload.

There are many kinds of load balancing you can do; depending on what kind of performance you need. However, in all cases, this is how it works:

```
Load Balancer > Reverse Proxy > Application Server
```

There is no redirection here because in some cases, the reverse proxy is also the load balancer (nginx is commonly configured this way). The entire request is passed on.

Now in some scenarios (again, depending on your application use profile), there may be one or more *static cache hosts*; which store your cached assets. These typically have their own subdomain (assets.example.com) or they may be offloaded to some CDN (foo.s3.amazon.com for example).

The application server makes sure that any requests to static assets have their URLs pointed to the cache servers; so that these requests don't touch the load balancers.

If however, your cache is behind your load balancer, then your load balancer is configured to route requests matching a domain prefix to a different set of back end servers. In the case where your load balancer and your reverse proxy is the same (as typically nginx use case), then the reverse proxy serves the asset request directly.

In all this - for the browser - there is no difference because the FQDN doesn't change. The DNS is configured for multiple load balancers (you can configure multiple hosts on the same IP using [virtual ip addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_IP_address)).

Now, to your actual problem:

> All I want is somehow telling to browser to ask the same domain from
>   another address like what dns does.

The way to do this is to have the browser request from *one domain*, and then have your load balancer or reverse proxy listen on all requests from this domain.

The LB/RP would then decide (based on the resource requested) either to serve the request directly (as is the case with a caching reverse proxy like nginx) or to pass it on to another server.

In the case of a non-cached asset (like if you request `index.php` or similar), the LB/RP will then pass this request to any backend (or upstream, as they are called) servers configured to handle that request. There can be multiple servers configured to serve the same type of request, for the same domain.

So, you can configure 4 backend servers that have the same codebase, to serve any requests that end in `.php`. Depending on the rules configured in the LB/RP, one of these servers is sent the request - the key part is - *this redirection does not happen using HTTP*.

Once the upstream servers are finished processing the request, the send the response back to the "requester" (in this case, the LB/RP), it will then send the request back to the client (the browser).

For the browser, the domain never changes and it is blissfully unaware of what is going on in the background.  Exactly how `gmail.com`, `google.com`, etc. work. The browser domain doesn't change, but one of any number of servers (located any number of places) are actually servicing the request.

Comment: However your tottaly right about the typical LB but as you mentioned think of something like a cdn LB for my case. In a typical LB cache solution, a LB can be a reverse proxy talking to a cluster of cache servers. Even some can implement an HA solution to boost things.

Comment: in that case there is no worry about changes in domains. But in a CDN manner, it should choose the best near cache server to the user's location. and thats why most CDNs are using GEODNS to handle things and by GEO dns there is no problem with changing domains too. But in my case I need the LB get HTTP request first and then choose the content server and let user communicate directly with the chosen server and that's where domain changes in redirection

Comment: Again thank you for the answer, You covered all the aspects for a common LB reverse proxy cache solution. But here, getting the request in http and then trying to make user communicate directly with another cache server cause the problem and sadly it sounds there is not any proper solution for this. what do you think?

Comment: P.S.S The way I started my question sounds I'm defining a typical reverse proxy LB's job. but actually I meant to jump right over what I'm trying to implement